# Get QML model of selected item

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a TreeView which I fill with items of QStandardItemModel

```
    QC1.TreeView{
         id: myTreeView
         model: myModel

         selection: ItemSelectionModel{
            id: mySelectionModel
            model: myModel
         }

         itemDelegate: ItemDelegate{
            MouseArea{
                 anchors.fill: parent
                 onClicked: {
                        console.log(styleData.index, model)
                 }
            }
            Text {
               id: name
               anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
               renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            }
         }
         QC1.TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            role: "name"
         }
    }

    Button{
       text: "Select third element"
       onClicked:{
          myTreeView.selection.select(myModel.getIndex(2,0), ItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect) //custom function, returns index(row, col)
          myTreeView.selection.setCurrentIndex(myModel.getIndex(2,0), ItemSelectionModel.SelectCurrent)
          //selection model data?
       }
    }
```

When I click any field I'm able to get this items `QModelIndex` and `QQmlDMAbstractItemModelData`. Button click automatically sets selected element to third element in model. `myTreeView.selection.currentIndex` will give me `QModelIndex` of selected item. How can I get `QQmlDMAbstractItemModelData` of selected item?

Comment: Please specify what do you want to get (e.g. why do you need `QQmlDMAbstractItemModelData` for)? Also it will be much easier to deal with your code if you could provide minimal working example.

Comment: I need `QQmlDMAbstractItemModelData` of a model item to bind it to simple component like TextArea to display a name of an item and it will be automatically updated when changed from C++